# Programmed Radio GET /context endpoint not being called

Tags: sonos

I am trying to setup programmed radio using the guide found at https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-add-features/add-programmed-radio/. The service calls getMetadata on my endpoint and /v1.0/radio/:containerId/version when I select the program to play, but there are no calls sent to my api after that.

The version endpoint is sending back

```
{
  "contextVersion": "CV:00001",
  "queueVersion": "QV:00001"
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The programmed radio endpoint uses the cloud queue API, so you must use the latest version, which is v2.1. Your request should look something like:

```
GET http://endpoint.example.com/v2.1/radio/smapicontainer:42/version
```

See [Cloud Queue API](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/cloud-queue-api/) and [Play audio (cloud queue)](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/play-audio/) for details.